# Php Scraping - How do I catch the variable in the source code?

Tags: php, web, screen-scraping

In the following html code, I want to catch the variable "1.31". Thank you for your help already.

```
Source Code
    <div style="font-size:20px">1.31 <i class="fa fa-try"></i> <span style="text-decoration: line-through; color:#919191; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 7px; margin-right: 5px; float:left" itemprop="price" content="1.55">1.55 <i class="fa fa-try" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="TL"></i></span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
    </div>

<?php

$url = "https://www.oyunfor.com/knight-online/gb-gold-bar";

$url_connect = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('@<div style="font-size:20px">(.*?)<i@si',$url_connect,$results);

print_r($results);

?>
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: So, use a DOM parser to read the html markup and then pick whatever content you like. Regular expressions are not really well suited for parsing html...

Comment: Apart from that: you code works perfectly fine. `$results[1]` holds the string `1.31`.

Comment: @Martin, I can't catch this variable with the code I am using

Comment: @arkascha, are you sure? I cant see "1.31" alone

Comment: Sure, it is captured in `$results[1]` which is an array holding exactly that string as single element. The reason why it is an array is because you use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`. I pointed that out in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine, I would however suggest a minor modification:

```
<?php
$markup = <<<HTML
    <div style="font-size:20px">1.31 <i class="fa fa-try"></i> <span style="text-decoration: line-through; color:#919191; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 7px; margin-right: 5px; float:left" itemprop="price" conten
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
    </div>
HTML;

preg_match('@<div style="font-size:20px">(.*?)<i@si', $markup, $results);
var_dump($results[1]);
```

The output of that is:

```
string(5) "1.31 "
```

---

UPDATE:

As you point out in the comments below you do *not* get the expected result if instead of using static markup as shown in the example for demonstration purpose you implement an internal http request fetching that markup from some remote server as you showed in your question.

Reason for that is that the markup you receive that way does not match the example you gave in your question. It differs slightly which causes your regular expression not to match. That is the main reason why regular expressions are considered a bad approach to parse such markup: they break to easily the moment some minor changes occur to the subject markup.

To be more specific: the markup your receive back actually is invalid. You probably did not realize that because you visualized it in a browser. But note that browser try to "fix" things to make it usable. For debugging you need to look at things without such intermediate layers to learn what you actually deal with. Here you should have dumped the markup you receive into some log file.

Anyway: you can modify your regular expression slightly to allow it to match again. This is what I would suggest, using that results in the same output again as shown above.

```
@<div\s+[^>]*style="?font-size:20px"?[^>]*>(.*?)<i@si
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: When I use file_get_contents, gives the result "Array()".  So, How can I run without using markup?

Comment: @CanKorkmaz Sounds like you again used `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`...

Comment: no i'dont :) <?php

$url = "https://www.oyunfor.com/knight-online/gb-gold-bar";

$url_connect = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('@<div style="font-size:20px">(.*?)<i@si',$url_connect,$results);

print_r($results);

?>

Comment: Then check what exactly is contained in `$result` and in the payload you receive as markup from the internal request. Please add such information to the question itself as an "update". Thanks.

Comment: @CanKorkmaz Reason why things fail is that the request you make in background does _not_ return what you claim in your question. The style attribute contained in that html markup the server returns is invalid, it is not contained in quote chars, which is why the regular expression does not match. You understand now why I claimed in my first comment to the question that a regular expression is a bad tool to scrape html markup?

Comment: @CanKorkmaz I updated the answer to help you solve that new issue. Have fun!